# OpenGL double precision

Tags: matlab, opengl, paraview

in the meantime, is there a way to dictate MATLAB or Paraview or any other application that uses OpenGL to do stuff in double precision ? I could use a workaround for my problems, but I prefer not to :) Thanks!

EDIT:
I try to be more specific about the problem/issue. First two images:
[image: openGL rendered]

[image: Other renderer]

The first one is rendered using openGL, the second (fine one) is rendered after typing the "opengl neverselect" method, which switches to another renderer. Since I experience quite simiular renderering problems in Paraview as well, I am quite sure that this is OpenGL specific and not the "fault" of matlab or Paraview. When I shift the values as mentioned in the comment below, I get smoothly rendered images as well. I assume that is because my data range has a huge offset from zero and the precision in the rendering routine is not accurate enough and produces serious rounding errors in the rendering calculations.

Thus, I would like to know if you know some way (in MATLAB, Paraview, in the OS settings) to set the rendering precision higher ( i read that gpus/OpenGL usually calculate in float)

Comment: Part of your question seems to be cut off...

Comment: actually not ;) I experience plotting problems in matlab and paraview due to single precisoin in hardware opengl. (i know because if i shift the range of my variables closer to zero and thus increasing the relative accuracy, the plotting gets better.) however, i do not really want to shift the data due to dependencies in the evaluation process

Comment: Unless Matlab is using half floats, then you shouldn't be getting artifacts that bad. (Recall that a normal float has ~6 significant figures.) Is your graphics driver up to date? I strongly suspect that this is caused by a bug somewhere, and the graphics driver is a good place to start.

Comment: Graphics driver are up to date... what about the z-axis? i have values that are barely representable with float there: z(1) =  7.356913341356019e+005, z(2) =  7.356913341772569e+005 , difference in the 11th digit

Comment: Oh, in that case you do actually need more precision than a float can provide. The fact that Matlab didn't notice this on its own does not bode well. If you are lucky it might have a switch somewhere to increase the precision, but it does not look like Matlab was designed to handle this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

First off, this has nothing to do with OpenGL. The part of MATLAB actually doing the plotting is written in some compiled language, and relies on OpenGL just for displaying stuff to the screen.

The precision used (double/float) is hard coded into the program. You can't have the OS or something force the program to use different data types. In certain cases you might be able to make the relevant changes to the source code of a program and then recompile, but this doesn't sound like it is applicable in your case.

This doesn't mean that there isn't a way to do what you want in MATLAB. In fact, since the program is specifically designed to do numeric computation there almost certainly is a way to specify the precision. You would need to provide more detailed information on your issue (screenshot?) if you want to get further guidance.

Comment: i updated my post :) I would be glad if you could have a look at it